# How do I choose over two python functions on terminal using sys and not argparse?

Tags: python, terminal, sys

I've two functions, and I want to choose function `message()` or function `number()` on a `UNIX` terminal.

This example I define the function will be used inside `if __name__ == "__main__":`:

```
import sys

def message(m=sys.argv[2]):
    print(" {} ".format(m))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    message()
```

At terminal *Inputting*:

```
$python test.py python!
```

*Outupts*:

```
python!
```

Then when I've two functions and call just one of them:

```
import sys

def message(m=sys.argv[1]):
    print(" {} ".format(m))

def number(n=sys.argv[1]):
    print(" {} ".format(n+2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #code that should be here
```

Comment: Do you mean *"how can I implement a command line interface"*? Have you considered doing some research?

Comment: @jonrsharpe he wants implement `message or number` based on the input from user

Comment: Then go and Google for that. `argparse` is a good start.

Comment: its a example... ofc they do the same, i want to choose one or another

Comment: an easy way would be to use `dictionary and sys.argv ` @AndreL

Comment: thx for the reference @VigneshKalai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical (and, in my view, correct) way to do this is to create a mapping of argument values to functions, which is simple to implement, efficient and easily scalable:

```
import sys

def message(m):
    print(" {} ".format(m))

def number(n):
    print(" {} ".format(int(n) + 2))  # you can't add integers to strings...

FUNCTIONS = {
    'message': message, 
    'number': number
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FUNCTIONS[sys.argv[1]](*sys.argv[2:])
```

Note the use of `*` to pass the rest of the arguments to the function - see [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761). This has removed the requirement for `sys.argv` to have a third value to create the functions, which could be a problem if you decide to reuse those functions elsewhere.

This will raise a `KeyError` if the user enters an invalid function name; you can handle this and give them a more specific error message if you like (either with `sys.argv[1] in FUNCTIONS`, which will be more efficient than checking in a list, or using `try` and `except`).

If you want a more complex CLI, with e.g. flags and specific value types, you should use something like [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) or [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/5/).

Comment: @VigneshKalai if they wanted to comment, they would have

Comment: I commented just for future reference if someone wants to point the mistake and I would not be using `*sys.argv[2:]` it causes error for this sample if more than two arguments are passed through command line

Comment: `number() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given) when this is given python test.py message 1 2 3`

Comment: @VigneshKalai yes, because the additional parameters *aren't supported*. In my view, getting a clear exception is better than silently ignoring subsequent parameters.

Comment: accepted I will just leave my comment to stay for the help of others

Comment: Very clear, thx for the explanation and the answer @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 2):

You definitively asked the wrong question. Your question is "how do arguments work on Python", and for working with arguments you have two options I'm aware of:

- Using sys.argv: you need to write something like `if "message" in
  sys.argv`
- Using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) which is a far better solution

Comment: Could you outline *how* you would use `argparse` for this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe there are multiple usage examples that I'll not write here, as they are in the documentation.

Comment: That is [not very useful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: so dumping the documentation is a useful example?

Comment: I'm not saying you should just "*[dump] the documentation"* - I'm asking you to provide a minimal example that shows *how* you could solve the OP's problem with `argparse`, rather than effectively just saying *"go and read the `argparse` docs"*, which is a comment at best.